# How to restrict symbolic variable range in Sage

Tags: sage

I am trying to simplify an real expression which contains a singularity. Is there any way to restrict the variable range to exclude the singularity and thereby permit symbolic simplification? For example,

```
var('a b c')
b = a / (1 - a^2)
c = 2*b / (1 + sqrt(1+4*b^2) )
c
```

Were 'a' restricted to -1 < a < 1, there would be no singularity in 'b'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of singularity is no obstacle to symbolic simplification. Sage  simplifies rational functions (which typically have singularities) just fine.

I suspect you tried `c.simplify()` and were disappointed by the result. As the [documentation says](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/expression.html#sage.symbolic.expression.Expression.simplify), this isn't a command you want. `c.simplify_full()` is a better general-purpose simplification routine:

```
c.simplify_full()

-2*a/(a^2 + (a^2 - 1)*sqrt((a^4 + 2*a^2 + 1)/(a^4 - 2*a^2 + 1)) - 1)
```

But to get more done, you have to be specific in what you want to be simplified. Here it's the radical expression, so let's try

```
c.canonicalize_radical() 

-1/a
```

Well... this is the correct result for large values of a, which is the intended behavior, per the [documentation](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/expression.html#sage.symbolic.expression.Expression.canonicalize_radical). If you want Sage to pick the correct branch when a is small, let a= 1/x. Then Sage will take the branch for large x, hence small a.

```
var('a b c x')
a = 1/x
b = a / (1 - a^2)
c = 2*b / (1 + sqrt(1+4*b^2) )
c.canonicalize_radical()
```

Output: 1/x, which is a.

---

To directly answer your question about restriction: `assume(a>-1, a<1)` does this to an extent. However, not all commands use the information from `assume`; in particular `canonicalize_radical` does not.

Comment: Many thanks. I was unaware of *canonicalize_radical()*. (And I see that I have fallen behind in the release cycle; mine only has the now deprecated *radical_simplify()*.)

Comment: I use https://cloud.sagemath.com/ which stays up to date without me having to do anything...